# Python Flask: User Downloading Scraped Images

Tags: python, flask, download

I have a little script that is an image scraper. Essentially, you provide the script with  a link and it downloads all the images on the webpage to a folder on your desktop.  I would like the same functionality but on the browser.  I ant users to enter a link and the script starts downloading the images from the link to their computer.  My Code Is Below:

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/Downlading', methods=['POST'])
def Downlading():
   url= request.form['url']
   start = request.form['start']
   end = request.form['end']
   dphy = image_downloader(url) #this is the script that saves the images
   return str(dphy)
```

I am able to get the user url and pass it to image_downloader, which downloads the images.  The problem is that the images get downloaded from the command prompt.  I want the script to run inside the browser, just like it would run in my IDE.  Sorry if this is confusing.

My HTML code:

```
    <form action="/Downlading" method="POST" >
        URL: <input type="text" name="url"><br/>
        Start: <input type="text" name="start"><br/>
        End: <input type="text" name="end"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="form" value="Submit" />

    </form>
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code?

Comment: If you input the url in the website, the images get downloaded form the URL, but the download show in the command prompt. Should it not download in the browser

Comment: You have to create an HTML template for it to be placed on.

Comment: I am a beginner with html and flask. Could you please elaborate how i can add it on the HTML.

Comment: Sure thing - just added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an HTML template for the variable to be reflected on. For example:

HTML - upload.html:

```
<html>
<title>Example on StackOverflow</title>
<p> The str representation of the variable dphy is {{ dphy }} </p>
</html>
```

Python (add this to existing flask script):

```
@app.route('/Downlading', methods=['POST'])
def Downlading():
   url= request.form['url']
   start = request.form['start']
   end = request.form['end']
   dphy = image_downloader(url) #this is the script that saves the images
   return render_template('upload.html', dphy=str(dphy))
```

This should work, but I can't test it right now so I'm not positive.  This is the basic idea for passing variables through Flask - create a template that uses the variable, then pass it in explicitly when rendering that created template.